# Debugging the solution in visual studio 2013. Debugger point is not setting at SaveItem method

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, visual-studio-2013

I am debugging a SharePoint 2013 solution in Visual Studio and was setting the debugger to the SaveItem method that is overridden. Why does this not get triggered? Following is my code,

```
<%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SPFormsWPSolnUserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="FormProject.SPFormsWPSoln.SPFormsWPSolnUserControl" %>


<table runat="server">
        <tr>
            <td><label runat="server" id="labelName">Name:</label></td>
            <td><SharePoint:InputFormTextBox runat="server" ID="inputText1"></SharePoint:InputFormTextBox></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <label runat="server" id="labelAddr">Address:</label></td>
            <td><SharePoint:InputFormTextBox runat="server" ID="InputFormTextBox1" TextMode="MultiLine"></SharePoint:InputFormTextBox></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label runat="server" id="labelState">State:</label></td>
            <td><SharePoint:InputFormTextBox runat="server" ID="InputFormTextBox2"></SharePoint:InputFormTextBox></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label runat="server" id="labelCity">City:</label></td>
            <td><SharePoint:InputFormTextBox runat="server" ID="InputFormTextBox3"></SharePoint:InputFormTextBox></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><SharePoint:SaveButton runat="server" ID="draftSave1" ControlMode="New"></SharePoint:SaveButton></td>
            <td><SharePoint:GoBackButton runat="server" ID="cancelButton1" ControlMode="New"></SharePoint:GoBackButton></td>

        </tr>
    </table>

------------------------------Functionality Part-----------------------------


using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;

namespace FormProject.SPFormsWPSoln
{

    public partial class SPFormsWPSolnUserControl : UserControl
    {       
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {          
          //  NewSaveButton gn = new NewSaveButton();
         //   labelTest.InnerText = "";         
        }
    }

    public class NewSaveButton : SaveButton
    {
        protected override bool SaveItem()
        {
            bool success = base.SaveItem();
            SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Site;
            SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();

            site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

            SPList list = web.Lists["Customers"];
            SPListItem itemToAdd = list.Items.Add();
            itemToAdd["CustomerID"] = 90;
            itemToAdd["CustomerName"] = "RadioMirchi";
            itemToAdd["CustomerAddress"] = "Vile Parle, Mumbai";
            itemToAdd["CustomerState"] = "Maharashtra";
            itemToAdd["CustomerCountry"] = "India";
            itemToAdd.Update();

            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
            site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
            web.Dispose();
            site.Dispose();
            return success;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have created a derived class for SaveButton, but it is not used on the form. And since the new control is never loaded, it will not get hit during debugging.

In your form code "SharePoint:SaveButton" use your NewSaveButton, take a look at this link for hints on how to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249295/override-sharepointsavebutton-in-custom-form-template

Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for information, but here they are creating and utilizing asp.net server control. What actually I am looking for is that to use SharePoint button control on server side coding and do customization on its PreSaveAction on server side is it possible.